# Spring binding: how to work with something like map?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, binding

I have to write a WS that respects a contract I very don't like but that's the work.

For a given request, I have some simple named parameters like user(Integer).

For the moment, it's easy, I wrote a command object with this two field and my request is:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public void request(Cmd cmd) {
    [impl]
}
```

Now the bad parts: I can have any couple of  ID=blabla,blabla,blabla

For example, request could be /?user=4&10=ok&3432=Simple,effective

Do you have any solutions that could be nice as having a Map in object command, with one or two Spring binding annotations?
Of course, it would be nice if user (and others like that) where not included in the map ^^

Cause I wrote something like this in the endpoint code, but I find it ugly:

```
final Enumeration<String> paramNames = request.getParameterNames();
while (paramNames.hasMoreElements()) {
    String paramName = paramNames.nextElement();
    String[] paramValues = request.getParameterValues(paramName);
    cmd.getMap().put(Integer.valueOf(paramName), paramValues[0]);
}
```

**Edit**

I'd like something like that (if possible)

```
public class SubmitTaskCmd {
private Integer userID;
private String hash;
    private Integer taskID;
    private Map<Integer, String> others = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

    public Map<Integer, String> getOthers() {
        return others;
    }

    public void setOthers(final Map<Integer, String> others) {
        this.test = test;
    }

    public Integer getUserID() {
        return userID;
    }

    public void setUserID(final Integer userID) {
        this.userID = userID;
    }

    public String getHash() {
        return hash;
    }

    public void setHash(final String hash) {
        this.hash = hash;
    }

    public void setTaskID(final Integer taskID) {
        this.taskID = taskID;
    }

    public Integer getTaskID() {
        return taskID;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I misunderstood, yes, very simply

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public void request(@RequestParam MultiValueMap<String, String> allParams) {
```

Note that there is no `name` attribute for the `@RequestParam` annotation. [This is explained in the javadoc of `@RequestParam`.](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html?is-external=true)

Comment: Surely, but I would like to my cmd object with user field (and the others I didn't mention) :s

Comment: @farvilain Can you show us what your command object actually looks like? I don't think I understand what you want.

Comment: @farvilain No, you won't be able to do that automatically with Spring's default configuration. It's very customized logic. What you are already doing seems appropriate. Just don't forget to ignore to properties you already have mapped for you.